# header div height not including absolute positioned div

Tags: css, html, background, css-position

I have been running into problems with the height of the header in a site for a uni project.

What I want to achieve is a header which contains a nav, background image slider (which is 100% wide) and speech bubble, with the site content below the header.

At the moment I have it all working as it should be, but the height of the header is not taking into consideration the background image slider, the reason for this being that it (the background-slider) has had to be positioned absolutely. With the current state of the site, I have added a header height in em, this gives me the required spacing on my laptop, but when moving to larger resolution the height is insufficient and the site content runs into the image.

My question is, is there a way of maintaining the current layout but including the functionality of the adjustable header height?

Current site is at: http://beta.immbudden.com

If you are viewing on screen size larger than 1366 x 768, you will see what I mean.

Any help at all would be really appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a diagram/picture of what you're trying to do? I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to describe.

Comment: yes dude, sorry, its quite hard to describe, so see the image below.

http://beta.immbudden.com/ss1.jpg
In image 1 you see how it is on my screen, background slider behind all other content, nav at the top, the speech bubble underneath, then the "about" content displayed below all of this.

In image 2, I have zoomed out, effectively changing the resolution of the window and whats happened is the about text has shifted up to where the background is.

Comment: In my markup, nav, background-slider & speech are all in the header, nav & speech are relative and slider is absolute position. What I want to achieve is keeping the current layout, but keep the spacing between the background slider and the about section when resized.

Comment: I think that if I make the background image relative, nav absolute, and speech bubble relative, then use z-index to position each? Would that be right do you think?

Comment: I still don't understand what the desired look is.

Comment: the desired look is as it appears in 1, nav at the top, slider as the background, speech bubble in front of it, but with the about section always below the bottom of the slider, even when the resolution is changed

Comment: just managed to fix it myself there amigo, had to change the order of things in the html etc, answer below. thanks for trying to help anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually managed to fix it myself. I positioned the nav absolute, speech bubble absolute and background-slider relative. I then gave each appropriate z-index's. I also had to change the order that each was called in the html, placing the slider from being called first, to last.

Hope this manages to help someone else, and if you need it explained any better just comment here :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `bottom-margin` to the header equal to the height of the absolutely positioned nav.

Comment: the nav isn't actually positioned absolutely, the only thing that is absolute is the background slider, the rest is relative

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the height of the header in pixels? If you have a set height nav and the image slider, you should be able to just set it.

Comment: it works the same as the em's will though. because with a bigger screen size, the width of the background image is going to adjust, as will the height. so atm for me, 700px height would be perfect for the height of the header, but if the resolution is increased to say 1680 x 1050 then the same problem is going to occur. The reasons for using em's throughout the pg anyway is because I am going to be making the site responsive.